# How to extend the HtmlHelper with the IDictionary<string, object> overload?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I created an extension method for the HtmlHelper which works very well. Now I need to create the overload that receives an IDictionary so I can add a css class to it so I tried the following:

```
public static MvcHtmlString EnumDropDownListFor<TModel, TEnum>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TEnum>> expression)
{
    return EnumDropDownListFor(htmlHelper, expression, null);
}

public static MvcHtmlString EnumDropDownListFor<TModel, TEnum>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TEnum>> expression, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
{
    var items = DoSomething();

    return htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expression, items, htmlAttributes);
}
```

When I tried to use it in my view I still got the following exception:

> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1928:
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not
>   contain a definition for 'EnumDropDownListFor' and the best extension
>   method overload
>   'LIMM.Web.HtmlHelpers.HtmlDropDownExtensions.EnumDropDownListFor(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary)' has some
>   invalid arguments

Obviously I'm not extending the method correctly but so google hasn't been my friend in finding a way to accomplish this. A little help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**: As I type the code in the view, intellisense does give me both overloads. The error happens when I run the application.

Comment: Did you make sure to add a using statement to your view so it knows how to find your extension methods?

Comment: have you seen this question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371652/custom-helper-in-asp-net-mvc3

I hope it will help.

Comment: @M.Babcock: Of course I did :) Like I said the original method worked fine, it's just the overload who has the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are trying use your helper using the commonest construction (pass html attributes as an anonymous object), so very probably you need an overload like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString EnumDropDownListFor<TModel, TEnum>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TEnum>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
{
    return EnumDropDownListFor(htmlHelper, expression, HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
}

public static MvcHtmlString EnumDropDownListFor<TModel, TEnum>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TEnum>> expression, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
{
    var items = DoSomething();

    return htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expression, items, htmlAttributes);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked. If you could put a short explanation as to why it must be like this I'm sure a lot of us will benefit from it.

Comment: We use to pass an object with the html attributes. Nowadays there is none kind of implicit cast from object to Dictionary<string,object>, so, we need to create an overload with this signature (html attributes as object), and call the original method converting this object to a Dictionary. The HTMLHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes method was written exaclty to accomplish this conversion.